# Use String reverse iterator and iterator as same type of object (C++)

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I am trying to use the same variable for both iterator and reverse iterator. However, I cannot find the common base class to do so.
I want to do something like this:

```
string a;
....
string::iterator i;
if (....)
    i = a.begin();
else
    i = a.rbegin();  //Error
....
```

Is there a good way of doing this?

Comment: Don't do it. They are two different things.

Comment: Can you extract the common code into a template?

Comment: There is no common base class, so no it will not work.

Comment: There is no requirement that `iterator` and `reverse_iterator` be of compatible types.   They are not necessarily classes either, so may not have a common base.   Try do have characteristics/traits in common though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no common type for `std::string::iterator` and `std::string::reverse_iterator`.

If you want to choose between them, you will need to have a different function for each type. The simplest way to do that is with a template

E.g.

```
template <typename Iterator>
void do_stuff(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    string a;
    if (...)
        do_stuff(a.begin(), a.end());
    else
        do_stuff(a.rbegin(), a.rend());
    return 0;
}
```